# Best way to pass the schema name as a variable to a query

Tags: anorm, string-interpolation

I have a PlayFramework server (with [Anorm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm)) which operates against a database with several schemas, all of them with the same tables.

Most of my "access to database" functions look like:

```scala
def findById(zoneName: String, id: Long): Option[Employee] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("""select *
          from """+zoneName+"""employee
          where employee._id = {id}"""
      .on(
          '_id -> id
        ).as(simpleParser.singleOpt)
    }
  }
```

But I know this is a wrong approach, because it is not SQL-Injection-safe and of course it is tedious to write in every function.

I want to use String interpolation to correct this, it works well with my `id` variable, but it doesn't with `zoneName`:

```
def findById(zoneName: String, id: Long): Option[Employee] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL"""select *
          from $zoneName.employee
          where employee._id = 1"""
      .as(simpleParser.singleOpt)
    }
  }
```

Gives me:

```
info] ! @6lenhal6c - Internal server error, for (GET) [/limbo/br/employee/1] ->
[info] 
[info] play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near «$1»
[info]   Position: 25]]
[info]  at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
[info]  at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
[info]  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
[info] Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near «$1»
[info]   Position: 25
[info]  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar:na]
[info]  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar:na]
[info]  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar:na]
[info]  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar:na
```

Tested also with `${zoneName}` with the same result.

Any help or advice about how to write this would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: You could set up the `search_path` to include the schema that you "currenly" work on before calling the functions. Or if you are using different databases users, the set the default `search_path` of that user to the schema name that user should use.

Comment: I've considered that option, but I discarded it because in the future I will need to support queries with more than 1 schema

Comment: Then I don't think you have any other option than concatenating the correct schema at runtime. This setup does look a bit strange to be honest. What is the problem that you are trying to solve with having the "same" table in different schemas? Maybe there is a better way to solve _that_

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution, yes. What I do is to have several companies (or branches from the same company) using the same database. And my server is a RESTful provider to access this data. In this way I keep the data separate from one company to another, but I keep the possibility of making queries that imply several schemas.

Maybe one approach is to have, as you suggest, db users with a search_path and making the queries with the right user? or keeping separated databases?

Comment: Do you know in advance which queries will be cross-schema? If you do,  you can create views in the "default" schema that combine the information from the other schemas. That way you can change the `search_path` in your request to match the current tenant and don't worry about accessing objects from different schemas in a single query.

Comment: Right now I don't, is just a thing to support in the future, thank you for the idea, I didn't considered it before. Based on your first comment, a possible solution could be keeping a "pool of N postgresql users" being N the number of schemas, and choosing the right user based on the user input, but it seems overly complicated to me

Comment: Another quick fix could be validate the schema names one time (maybe with a regex) and keep them stored in a map, in this way I'll avoid the SQL Injection manually

Answer (score 3):

Using Anorm String interpolation, any `$expression` is to be provided a parameter, that is to say if it's a string it will quoted by the JDBC driver.

If you want to substitute part of the SQL statement with string (e.g. dynamic schema), either you can use concatenation, or since latest versions (2.4.0-M3 or 2.3.8) the syntax `#$expr`.

```scala
val table = "myTable"
SQL"SELECT * FROM #$table WHERE id=$id"
// SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=?
```

Comment: I'll test #$expr way, I didn't know this syntax and seems good. Do you know if this just replaces the string? in that case it will not solve my SQL injection problem. Where can I find the documentation of this?

Comment: This syntax just allows to mix standard string interpolation with Anorm param interpolation. Standard string interpolation doesn't prevent SQL injection.